# Proyecto importado de Netbens de una maquina a otra

Tags: java

Al importar un proyecto de una máquina a otra no se ejecuta y produce un error al no encontrar el archivo:

> org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml.

Cómo lo resuelvo?

Comment: probaste en ir a buscar ese archivo y copiarlo a la nueva maquina(?)

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Hasta que no añadas mas información, me temo que tu pregunta quedará [en espera-¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), pero si editas tu pregunta y la mejoras, la comunidad puede optar por abrirla y darte una solución. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El proyecto que tratas de importar tiene referencias a Kotlin, tienes que instalar el plugin de Kotlin para Netbeans!

Solo existe plugin para la versión 8.1 y 8.2, instala e importa nuevamente tu proyecto.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/68590/kotlin